# Allow logged in user to vote only once on a suggestion (Django)

Tags: django, django-models

I've got two models on my Django site. An Event and suggested names for that event, in the case that the one I provide may not be the best. I want each user to only be able to vote on each suggestion once. They must be logged in to do so, so I know who they are. Any clue how I'd add that to these models?

```
class Event(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
    event_id = models.BigIntegerField(blank = 'TRUE', primary_key='TRUE')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank = 'TRUE')
    start = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank = 'TRUE', null = 'TRUE')
    end = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank = 'TRUE', null = 'TRUE')
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank = 'TRUE', null = 'TRUE')
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank = 'TRUE', null = 'TRUE')
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank = 'TRUE', null = 'TRUE')
    suggested = models.ManyToManyField('suggestedName', blank = 'TRUE', null = 'TRUE') 

class suggestedName(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank = 'TRUE', null = 'TRUE')
    votes = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way would probably be handling it in the code.

Before save, you check if object exists in `ManyToMany` field

You can do it in one of 2 ways i can think of in the models:

Create a new table that references the `User`, with the `Suggestion` and the `Event`

OR

Have a unique property on the [`through` table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

```
class Event(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
    event_id = models.BigIntegerField(blank = 'TRUE', primary_key='TRUE')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank = 'TRUE')
    start = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank = 'TRUE', null = 'TRUE')
    end = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank = 'TRUE', null = 'TRUE')
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank = 'TRUE', null = 'TRUE')
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank = 'TRUE', null = 'TRUE')
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank = 'TRUE', null = 'TRUE')
    suggested = models.ManyToManyField('suggestedName', blank = 'TRUE', null = 'TRUE', through='EventSuggestion')

class EventSuggestion(models.Model):
    #through table attributes
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    suggestion = models.ForeignKey(suggestedName)
    user = models.ForeignKey('User')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('event', 'suggestion', 'user')
```

Comment: The reason I use ManyToMany is because there can be multiple suggestions to one event. Then the users vote on them. Should I go for the latter option in this case?

Comment: Yeah, but then you are restricting it to one suggestion per user. I would recommend that. Please make sure you have thought through the implementation. This is based on my understanding of what you are asking for

Comment: Perfectly reasonable to restrict each user to only one suggestion. If you're going to suggest something, you're going to suggest your best idea. That's actually an added bonus I hadn't even considered yet. One suggestion and one vote per suggestion

Comment: just edited the answer slightly. May be that fits your need better. Good luck

Comment: Hey, I get an error when I try to sync this. "'user' has a relation with model User, which has either not been installed or is abstract.". Do I want it linking to User (Django-provided implementation), or the Profile (Model I created)